# vb.net using power operator with DataTable().Compute

Tags: vb.net

I have a database with formulas for calculating the cost of a selected product based on the given input of a form field. It created the need to be able to evaluate a string as a mathematical expression.  After searching SO, I found a solution using `DataTable().Compute.

```
formulaToUse = Replace(formulaToUse, "x", coverArea.Text)                       
Dim result = New DataTable().Compute(formulaToUse, "")
MsgBox(result)
```

As you can see, I'm replacing "x" with the input value, and then evaluating the string as a mathematical expression.  The problem is, some of the formulas in my database require the use of the power operator (^) (i.e. 5*x^0.68) which throws the exception "The expression contains unsupported operator '^'."

So how do handle this? Is there a different operator I can / should use?

Comment: It *appears* to be not supported.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Comment: ok, forget it. I added the Ncalc reference successfully only to learn they dropped the power operator. ILcalc is doing the job nicely

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using [ILCalc](https://ilcalc.codeplex.com/) instead.

```
Dim calc = New CalcContext(Of Double)("x")
MsgBox(calc.Evaluate(formulaToUse, CDbl(coverArea.Text)))
```

thanks to @Plutonix for your input.